# Twitter Bootstrap: position list elements by first letter around the center (almost centered)

Tags: html, css, list, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a code that can be seen in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/at5ddLdq/1/)

```
<style>
    li{
        border:1px solid red;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
    <div id="outer">
        <ul  class="list-inline">
            <li class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">a</li>
            <li class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">bb</li>
            <li class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">ccccc</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

It displays text in the center of the cells on large screen horizontally and in one column for small devices.

To see that changes in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/at5ddLdq/1/) please move the vertical bar so the width will be changed.

**The question is:**

How to change the code so that the text alignment:

is the same for larger devices,

but for small devices it is aligned by first letters, but positioned in the center or around the center, i.e. the destination from the first letter to the left border are the same for all three lines of text, and the text doesn't go to the left or right from the center by changing the screen width.

Please **no javascript** if that's possible (still not sure).

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this supposed to be some sort of "enhanced" user experience or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `text-indent`, use media query to apply it to small screens.

```
/* only for small screens */
li {
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 2em; /* or any value you prefer */ 
}
```